# How to let the admin see specific buttons

Tags: php, session

I am working on a dashboard button on my website. This button only shows up when anyone is logged in, but the meaning of the button is to only show it to the admin.

Here is a part of the login function:

```
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = :userName AND userPassword =:userPassword");
        $query->bindParam(":userName", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(":userPassword", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();


        if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $user = $query->fetch();
            $_SESSION['login'] = $user;
            header("location: ../../index.php");
            die();
        }
    }
```

And here is the part of the index that needs to show the dashboard button for the admin:

```
<?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login']['userId'] ==  0)
            {
            echo '<a class="btn" name="login" href="functions/login/functions.php">Login</a>';


            }
            else
            {
                echo "<h3>Welkom " . $_SESSION['login']['userName']."</h3>";
                echo '<a class="btn" name="logout" href="functions/logout/logout.php">Logout</a>';
                echo '<a class="btn" name="dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>';
            }
            ?>
```

I cannot figure out what to do here. So if anyone can help I appreciate your help.

Comment: how do you check which user is admin ot not? what is the criteria?

Comment: in the database I have there is a row called: userAdmin. userAdmin is and INT and is standard 0 and for the admin it is 1. I don't have anything to check this yet.

Comment: So in that case store `userAdmin` in your session and check it afterwards is it 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login']['userId'] ==  0)
{
   if($_SESSION['login']['userAdmin']==1)
    { 
    //is admin (content for admin)
   }
   else
   {
    //not admin (content for no admin)
   }
   //content for both 
}
```